# Error while removing CrossPlatformui package

Tags: software-installation

Whenever I try to install an application, I get the crossplatformui error. I tried to remove it but got the following response from terminal. Please let me know how I can solve it.

```
sahana@sahana-Inspiron-N5010:~$ sudo apt-get install -f  
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree         
Reading state information... Done  
The following packages will be REMOVED:  
  crossplatformui  
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 1 not upgraded.  
1 not fully installed or removed.  
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.  
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y  
(Reading database ... 169569 files and directories currently installed.)  
Removing crossplatformui ...  
ztemtvcdromd: no process found  
dpkg: error processing crossplatformui (--remove):  
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1  
Errors were encountered while processing:  
 crossplatformui  
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)  
sahana@sahana-Inspiron-N5010:~$
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to forcely remove  `crossplatformui` package by running the below command on terminal,

```
sudo dpkg -P --force-all --force-remove-reinstreq crossplatformui
```